# Join query returns more rows than nested select query?

Tags: sql, select, join, sybase, sybase-ase15

I have the following queries:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM User u
INNER JOIN NAME n 
     ON u.UserId = n.UserId
    AND n.last = 'Joe';
--returns 1943

SELECT count(*)
FROM User u
WHERE u.UserId IN (
        SELECT n.UserId
        FROM NAME n
        WHERE n.last = 'Joe'
        );
--returns 1875
```

UserId is the primary key in table User, and a foreign key in table Name (not unique).

How come the join query returns more rows than the nested select query?  Shouldn't they be the same?

Thanks.

Comment: You have UserId with more than one Name

Comment: Try: ```select count(*), u.UserId
from User u join Name n on u.UserId = n.UserId and n.last = 'Joe'
group by u.UserId having count(*) > 1;``` to see who is duplicated

Comment: I see. It makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join equivalent of this query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM User u
WHERE u.UserId IN (
        SELECT n.UserId
        FROM NAME n
        WHERE n.last = 'Joe'
       );
```

would be:

```
SELECT count(distinct u.UserId)
FROM User u JOIN
     NAME n
     ON n.last = 'Joe' AND u.UserId = n.UserId;
```

The `distinct` takes care of the duplicates.

Comment: Makes sense now, couldn't wrap my head around it at first. Thanks.